# Разработка для Аndroid

Tags: java, android

Помогите с решением вопроса.

Скачал шаблон интернет-магазина на базе Андройд. Для того, что бы менять шаблон, нужно вносить изменения в файлы, то есть менять значения.

Когда я меняю значения, файл сохраняется. Но как только я открываю эмулятор, изменения не видны. Как с текстом, так и с картинками. То есть редактирую картинки в paint, они сохраняются, но в эмуляторе стоит неотредактированная картинка.

Переделать проект не помогает.

Comment: Не совсем понятно - какие значения можно менять в paint?

Comment: Возможно, вы не туда сохраняете файл, проверьте пути и название файла. Также можете попробовать назвать новый файл иначе и попробовать указать другой путь.

Comment: попробуйте полностью пересобрать проект или почистить кеш android studio

Comment: Я пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: Не менять значения, а редактировать картинку.


Пересобрать не помогает.

Comment: У вас написано "вносить изменения в файлы, то есть менять значения"...